# dealing with c++ struct in UML

Tags: c++, uml

How do we deal with the C++ struct in UML class diagrams.
Should I consider it as a class with the stereotype `<<Struct>>`?
And if this struct has a pointer to the struct type itself, what is the relationship between the struct and it self?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How do we deal with the C++ struct in UML class diagrams?"

structs behave like Classes in UML but all of their members are public.

"...if this struct has a pointer to the struct type itself, what is the relationship between the struct and it self?" - Self referential. It has a pointer to itself. [Answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797074/uml-class-aggregating-to-self)

Google searching is a brilliant thing :). Hope this answers your question. If you have any more, just drop a comment.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: "structs behave like Classes in UML but all of their members are public" structs don't even exist in UML, the OP has created a stereotype and the link is talking about C++ structs. You can say that the stereotype has the C++ semantics, and some C++ profiles do, but it's not the core UML doing that. e.g. a C# UML profile with the «struct» stereotype would have different semantics.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just answering the OP's question(s) though. The point is to lead him to the answer (as it was a simple google search away). How would you display a struct in UML then out of curiosity?

Comment: Nvm, found it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465146.aspx#NetProfile

Comment: And here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.1.2/com.ibm.xtools.viz.cpp.doc/topics/rmapping.html

Comment: awkward that the google search brings you here 